# Magento API says "looks like we got no XML document" but i am getting valid xml

Tags: php, soap, magento-1.7

So i started building something like a wrapper class for the SOAP API of Magento 1.7.0.2 CE following the instructions [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html#Introduction-SOAP)

```
<?php
    class magSoap
    {
        private $client;
        private $session;

        function __construct() 
        {
            $this->client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:7655/magento1702CE/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
            var_dump($this->client);
            file_put_contents("xml.txt",file_get_contents("http://localhost:7655/magento1702CE/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl"));
            $this->session = $this->client->login('test', '1234567890');

            echo "hello";
        }

        function test()
        {
            var_dump($this->client->call($this->session, 'sales_order.list'));
        }
    }

?>
```

when i run the following code

```
$tester = new magSoap();
$tester->test();
```

i get the following

[image: error]

googling the error the answer i keep seeing is that i got invalid XML so i navigated to the URL i used in `SoapClient` and [i didn't see anything wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjO2I.png). then i created that `file_put_contents` line so i could output the xml to a [text file](http://pastebin.com/Rgakx4ev) and use [this WSDL Analyzer](https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/) but doesn't show me any errors

[image: report]

the SOAP Login is test, the key is 1234567890, the SOAP Role has full access, i have disabled *"Auto-redirect to Base URL"*, php_soap is enabled in WAMP Server and PHP version is 5.6.25.

Why is it this code still wont work?

Answer (score 1):

I spent many hours in a integration with Magento..

In my case I found out that the SOAP Response of my call had some special html characters and then the SOAP considered is as not an XML response.

What helped me was putting a try-catch in the soap call and use the soap methods __getRequest() and __getResponse() to see what was going on.

Hope it helps someway :)